# Merging the "ati" tag into "amd-graphics"

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags

This tag merge will affect a lot of questions, so I think we should discuss it here before doing it.

To be clear:

- all [ati](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ati) questions will be tagged [amd-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd-graphics) after the merge.
- the [ati](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ati) tag will be a synonym for [amd-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd-graphics).

Should we do it?

Comment: Why? What's the reason for the merge to begin with

Comment: I proposed the merge because we have "intel-graphics" and "amd-graphics" and "nvidia", so having ati and amd-graphics didn't make sense. But then someone brought up in chat that the googleability of "ati" is probably important, which I hadn't thought about.

Comment: this is a tricky one, because I still think of ATI video cards, and I do not think of "AMD graphics cards"..

Comment: @Marco well the reason would be that it's factually correct. I'll mark it as deffered until AMD improves their marketing efforts. ;-)

Comment: Maybe merging amd-graphics into ati would make more sense, and at least get rid of the double-tags

Comment: +1 on Jorge's comment.  I'm thinking it'd make more sense to merge [tag:amd-graphics] into [tag:ati]

Comment: However, 'ati' is graphics, whereas 'amd-graphics' is subset of 'amd'.  So, instead suggest make 'ati' synonym of 'amd-graphics'.

Comment: When I think about `amd-graphics` I think about built in graphics in to AMD chipset motherboards but when googling for problems I will always search for ATI + chipset because that is the device name that shows up on devices. Until AMD decides to call off anything related with ATI, devices to call AMD to all they future devices and changes the name of the driver to something else other then ATI Catalyst I would say ATI exists and its more popular when doing searches for issues and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

The companies may have recently merged (or changed names - I don't know offhand), but my ATI Radeon graphics card was made by ATI, not AMD.  Have the drivers merged as well?

Certainly the lspci still reports:

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon RV250 If [Radeon 9000] (rev 01)

If I'm asking for help about this, I'm not going to know to use a tag referring to a new company name that my driver (or card) isn't reporting.  I'd vote to leave the tag as it is and let the amd-graphics tag refer to the new stuff that actually comes from amd (or reports so).  Can new marketing catch up with old hardware?  I doubt it is motivated to do so, yet old hardware doesn't change.

Comment: That is the point of a tag synonym. You can still use the [tag:ati] tag but it will be automatically converted to [tag:amd-graphics].

Comment: In that case, the only problem I see would be that in searching for ATI stuff for your old graphics card, then you'd end up with AMD stuff too that isn't relevant.  Probably not a big deal though.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the recent AMD distributed graphic cards are in fact labeled as *AMD Radeon* for example, I'd say we should go for it.

Googling for ATI results in the first four entries to be linked to http://amd.com and have a lot of AMD references in them. It think it is time to merge the tags as proposed if it happened already.