# Please revert merging amd-graphics tag into ati

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

there was a post a [few months ago](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14236/40581) about the [tag synonym](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1550/40581) and I just got reminded of if [today](https://askubuntu.com/q/756866/40581).

- The AMD ATI merger was almost 10 years ago (in 2006) and Wikipedia says AMD stopped using the ATI brand in 2010. (The AMD brand adopted the color red though, which may be why some of you still think ATI as a brand is in active use.)

  - The synonym suggestion in *2011* was uninformed and short sighted.
  - Discrete graphics are not that important anymore, most consumers today have iGPUs/APUs from *AMD* and Intel or SoCs.
  - To the average consumer this brand doesn't exist anymore because products sold under that brand are not competitive if they can be found on the shelves today.
  - Most consumers don't care about traditional brands of computer component manufacturers and nostalgia. (I had a Hercules monochrome adpater in my first computer and know about many other brands that have ceased to exist or returned in another form.)
- Now is the right time because **fglrx will be phased out with 16.04**, which already spawned a few questions about compatibility and performance.

  - Just look at the third link here in my post and tell me that tagging the question ati instead of amd-graphics isn't extremely confusing to a non-technical user who doesn't have a collection of inefficient and older than 5 years (outdated!) graphics cards.
  - The reverse, [ati](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ati) as a synonym of [amd-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd-graphics) is clear to every one without prior knowledge, and we can still add a short note to the tag wiki that explains why.

As a last resort just rename ati to amd-graphics if that is possible and other options are not available.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. If there aren't any objections I will do this sometime this week.

Comment: You didn't mention it (because there are none I assume), but I gotta ask: are there any drawbacks or disadvantages to unmerging?

Comment: They are synonyms (there's no sense having two tags about the same thing), they're just the wrong way around for modern popular use. We can reverse the synonym mapping and shunt all the questions over.

Comment: +1 just for comparing an ATI card to a Hercules card!  **:D**

Comment: @Fabby That's not what I said (∩︵∩) I wanted to say I know what the commenters on Pilot6's question are talking about, but I don't feel I'm that old. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have reversed the synonym. [ati](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ati) is now a synonym of [amd-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd-graphics). I left [amd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amd) unsynonymised since it is also a CPU brand and we have [intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/intel) and [intel-graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/intel-graphics).

Comment: [meta-tag:status-complete]?

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment. I have not enough rep.

I think we should merge 'ati' to 'amd-graphics', not the other way. Because AMD is the 'big guy', and ATI dies.